# Combinatorial Identities in Negative Binomial mgf derivation

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients, negative-binomial

I'm trying to understand how to derive negative binomial mgf and came accross this discussion

[Deriving Moment Generating Function of the Negative Binomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848449/deriving-moment-generating-function-of-the-negative-binomial)

I can't understand the step that assumes,

$$\binom {y+r-1}{r-1} = \binom{y+r-1}{y}$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! \, (n-k)!}.$$
This also implies
$$\binom{n}{n-k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)! \, k!}.$$
So
$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}.$$
Now repeat this with $n = y+r-1$ and $k = y$.